# Is Open MPI's reduce syncrhonized?

Tags: mpi, reduce

I am looking at the code here which I am doing for practice.

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/usingmpi/examples/simplempi/main.html

I am confused about the part shown here.

```
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Reduce(&mypi, &pi, 1, MPI::DOUBLE, MPI::SUM, 0); 
if (rank == 0) 
    cout << "pi is approximately " << pi 
         << ", Error is " << fabs(pi - PI25DT) 
         << endl;
```

My question is does the mpi reduce function know when all the other processes (in this case the programs with rank 1-3) have finished and that its result is complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All collective communication calls (Reduce, Gather, Scatter, etc) are blocking.

Comment: All [_collective_ communication calls](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node91.html#SECTION00500000000000000000) do, meaning that all processes will block until all the other processes in the specified group have reached a matching call.

Comment: While this is usually true in practice, the MPI standard [discourages relying on implicit synchronization](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node64.htm#Node64).  See comment under "Advice to users".  A collective is guaranteed to produce the required result by the time it returns, but is not necessarily synchronizing.  Imagine for example a broadcast that caches its result somewhere and then allows the root to proceed.  Just because MPI_Bcast returned on the root does not mean the other processes reached the corresponding MPI_Bcast call.

Comment: in case anyone is interested, I found out this is not the case for `Bcast()` in OpenMPI (1.6 linux x64). The broadcaster does not block but all receivers do block until message is sent by broadcaster. I would assume it would be the same for Gather (senders will not block but receiver will block).

Answer (score 5):

@g.inozemtsev is correct.  The MPI collective calls -- including those in Open MPI -- are "blocking" in the MPI sense of the word, meaning that you can use the buffer when the call returns.  In an operation like MPI_REDUCE, it means that the root process will have the answer in its buffer when it returns.  Further, it means that non-root processes in an MPI_REDUCE can safely overwrite their buffer when MPI_REDUCE returns (which usually means that their part in the reduction is complete).

However, note that as mentioned above, the return from a collective operation such as an MPI_REDUCE in one process has no bearing on the return of the same collective operation in a peer process.  The only exception to this rule is MPI_BARRIER, because barrier is defined as an explicit synchronization, whereas all the other MPI-2.2 collective operations do not necessarily need to explicitly synchronize.

As a concrete example, say that all non-root processes call MPI_REDUCE at time X.  The root finally calls MPI_REDUCE at time X+N (for this example, assume N is large).  Depending on the implementation, the non-root processes may return much earlier than X+N or they may block until X+N(+M).  The MPI standard is intentionally vague on this point to allow MPI implementations to do what they want / need (which may also be dictated by resource consumption/availability).

Hence, @g.inozemtsev's point of "You cannot rely on synchronization" (except for with MPI_BARRIER) is correct.